# Flash player not loading on some macs (Webview)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've created a mac application that is **not code signed** and released over my own website.

Application works fine on most macs, but some users saids that it produces bug on their macs.

I found out that their macs does not start "Flash Player ([Appname] Internet plug-in)" process in common.

My app uses Webkit WebView and it is plugin enabled. Works great on most computers and so does on my mac. But some users are getting this problem.

I'm expecting there may be some security issues or crash between other app. But I can't find out what it is.

Is there anything that I am missing or something that I could do?

Comment: This could seems stupid but... are you sure these users have the Flash Player plugin installed ?

Comment: Very likely - I don't have Flash installed on my laptop.

Comment: Yes. They also tried remove and reinstall but nothing changed.